# Sorting by price/quality ratio

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have this trivial problem I can't solve.

I have a list of names with a value (let's say strenght) and a price. I want to understand which is the most convenient depending on the price, a sort of price/quality ratio.

Example

```
NAME   STRENGTH  PRICE
BOB    48        17
CHRIS  51        17
MARK   49        15
```

I want to sort this data on the price/quality ratio

Comment: Is strength == quality?  Do you mean price/strength ratio?  What language are you using?  This question is unclear.

Comment: if strength == quality, just divide the two

Comment: Yeah I mean strenght == quality. I tried this way but the results didn't seemed right to me

Comment: @duffymo I'm not using any language yet, just a pen and some papers

Comment: So you mean price/strength?

Comment: Don't know what "tried this way" means.  You need to calculate the ratio and maintain the association between it and all the other variables.  Sort the ratios so you know what index they had in the original array.

Comment: I haven't got if you mean price/strength or vice versa

Comment: If you divide strength/price, you'll have strength per price. A greater ratio would mean you're getting more strength for the same price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your value (quality) is **strength** that each player has. It also has its **price**.
If you want to find out which player is the most valuable, you shall divide `strength/price`, because in result you'll get how many strength-units you can have for 1 price-unit. The more strength-units for 1 price-unit - the better player is, obviously.

Let's take a look at the data set below (sorted by `STR/PRI` ratio descending):

```
NAME   STRENGTH  PRICE  STR/PRI
JOHN   99        15      6,600
MARK   49        15      3,267
CHRIS  51        17      3,000
BOB    48        17      2,823
TOM    5         17      0,294
```

99 strength and only 15 price? Great, right? His ratio is 6,600.
Wait... 5 strength and 17 price? I wouldn't buy this one, and you? And look - his ratio is only 0,294.

Conclusion? The **best player has the highest `STR/PRI` ratio**.
Now if we add `PRI/STR` column to the table above (sorted from the best to the worst as above):

```
NAME   STRENGTH  PRICE  STR/PRI     PRI/STR
JOHN   99        15      6,600       0,151
MARK   49        15      3,267       0,306
CHRIS  51        17      3,000       0,333
BOB    48        17      2,823       0,354
TOM    5         17      0,294       3,400
```

You can easily notice that **the best player** (John) **has the lowest `PRI/STR` ratio**.

Answer (score 0):

We've clarified that you mean price/strength ratio.

Here's your original data set:

```
INDEX      NAME   STRENGTH  PRICE RATIO
1          BOB    48        17    0.354167
2          CHRIS  51        17    0.333333
3          MARK   49        15    0.306122
```

If I sort these by RATIO in ascending order, the indexes are (3, 2, 1).  I can tell what order NAME, STRENGTH, and PRICE need to be in by using those indexes.

Use any sorting algorithm you wish on the RATIO array and get the indexes back.  Use these to refer to the original data in the order of ascending RATIO.

Comment: Ok, so the lesser is the ratio, the more affordable is the player, right?

Comment: You know what a ratio is, right?  A lower ratio means either lower price, higher strength, or both.